# JTDS Driver: Could not find a Java charset equivalent to collation 2C04D01000

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

Looking a solution for strange JTDS error message: Could not find a Java charset equivalent to collation 2C04D01000.

I tried to pass file.encoding and user.encoding parameters without any success.

Comment: What is the collation of the SQL Server database you're trying to connect to? Run this command to find out: `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('YourDatabaseName', 'Collation')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found for the issue is to use Microsoft JDBC driver instead of JTDS.